# Reverse of surround with for pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I have a code:

```
foo(bar(a,b))
```

If I regret the foo function i need to place the cursor on the beginning of the bar, back space, then go to the end of bar(a,b) and delete the extra parenthesis.

I want a shortcut to make:

```
foo(bar(a,b)) -> bar(a,b)
```

In minimal effort.
I searched and found surround with functionality which is the opposite of that.

Comment: You could use Macros, Place your cursor on outermost opening bracket, 
And Record macro with following actions.   Shift + Home -> Delete -> End -> Backspace

Comment: [Unwrap command](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/unwrapping-and-removing-statements.html) is for this yet the docs don't specify if it works for function calls.

Comment: Thanks @saurabhbaid.
Although it's a bit problematic in the case the function is not the last in the line:
"foo(bar(a,b)) + 5" will result in:
"bar(a,b)) + "
If you know a good way to solve this that would be great.
ivan_pozdeev thanks, I will try that and respond.